# How to extend the HtmlHelper With Ajax effects in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

This is an ASP.NET MVC 5 Project.

I extended the `HtmlHelper`. Hers the code:

```
public static class ValidationMessageExtend
{
    public static HtmlString ValidateionUseridTooltip(this HtmlHelper helper, string name)
    {
        if (
            helper.ViewData.ModelState[name] == null ||
            helper.ViewData.ModelState[name].Errors == null ||
            helper.ViewData.ModelState[name].Errors.Count == 0
            )
        {
            return new HtmlString("");
        }

        TagBuilder innerTag = new TagBuilder("div");
        innerTag.Attributes.Add("class", "tooltip-inner");
        innerTag.InnerHtml = helper.ViewData.ModelState[name].Errors[0].ErrorMessage;
        TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("div");
        tag.Attributes.Add("class", "tooltip fade top in");
        tag.Attributes.Add("role", "tooltip");
        tag.Attributes.Add("id", "tooltip387165");
        tag.Attributes.Add("style", "top: 5px; left: 55px; display: block;");
        tag.InnerHtml = "<div class='tooltip-arrow' style='left: 50 %;'></div>" + innerTag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);

        return new HtmlString(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
    }
}
```

The purpose of this extension is to change the `@Html.ValidationMessageFor`  default style.

I have included `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` and `jquery.validate.js` in my view.

I would like to use my own extension `@Html.ValidateionUseridTooltip("UserID")`. It can not be the same as using `@Html.ValidationMessageFor`, and has to trigger the verification without refreshing the page.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you added  `<appSettings><add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/><add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/></appSettings>` in your web.config? Does your normal ValidationMessageFor work for clientside validation?

Comment: Yes,my web config allrelady set,you set is MVC default set,and ValidationMessageFor in clientside validation is work.but my extend ValidateionUseridTooltip is not work without refreshing the page.

Comment: Your extension method does not have the required `data-*` attributes necessary for client side validation. You should not be trying to reinvent the wheel. You can create an extension method by making use of the inbuilt methods and adding the additional class attributes etc.

Comment: thanks for Stephen Muecke answers,but how can i to implement? Can you give me a specific solution or example?

Comment: I'll add an answer in 30 min or so, but you have other issues as well such as invalid html (your generating duplicate `id` attributes) and then your adding inline styles as well as class names (poor practice)

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect the html that the `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` method generates it is, for a valid state (where `XX` is the property name)

```
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="XX" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

and for an invalid state

```
<span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="XX" data-valmsg-replace="true">
    <span for="Name" generated="true" class="">The XX field is required.</span>
</span>
```

Nowhere in your extension method do you generate the necessary `data-*` attributes used by the `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` for client side validation. And nor should your. Instead make use of the inbuilt methods and add your additional attributes using the methods overloads.

```
public static MvcHtmlString ValidateionUseridTooltipFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
{
    var attributes = new { @class = "tooltip fade top in", role = "tooltip" };
    MvcHtmlString validation = ValidationExtensions.ValidationMessageFor(helper,expression, null, attributes);
   return validation;

   // or if you want to enclose this in the div
   TagBuilder div = new TagBuilder("div");
   div.Attributes.Add(....);
   div.InnerHtml = validation.ToString();
   return validation; 
}
```

Note that you have not shown the output your expecting so its not clear which  attributes you want applied to which elements so the above code will need to be adjusted to suit your needs.

Note also that the inner `<span>` element in the html above gets added by the validation plugin files and you have no control over it unless you modify the files.

In addition, you should not be adding an `id` attribute (duplicate `id` attributes are invalid html) and adding a series of class names and the adding inline `style` attributes is unnecessary and poor practice (you should add another class name and create the css for it or modify existing css files)

And finally, if your want to understand how the `ValidationMessageFor()` method works, you can inspect the [source code here](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/ValidationExtensions.cs).